# it is the final rubber stamp on his status

Tags: expressions, pronouns

> [**Messi celebration is most-liked Instagram post**](https://www.fifa.com/fifaplus/en/articles/world-cup-2022-qatar-messi-celebration-argentina-france)
>
> Lionel Messi's Instagram message celebrating Argentina's World Cup win has become the most popular post in the social media platform's history, with 56 million likes. 
> Messi finally won international football's greatest prize after Argentine edged out France 4-2 on penalties after a thrilling 3-3 draw in Sunday's final at Lusail Stadium. 
> For the seven-time Ballon d'Or winner, **it** is the final **rubber stamp** on his status as the greatest footballer of his generation, and arguably the greatest of all time. 
> Now, Messi has another record to his name, with his post in the wake of Argentina's success surpassing the previous high-water mark held by the World Record Egg, which gained 55.9 million likes.

In the third sentence, what does **it** refers to? Also, why use the expression "rubber stamp" here?

Answer (score 1):

rubber stamps were (are) used together with a signature to certificate documents.

**it is the final rubber stamp on his status**
means that he got the ultimate confirmation on his "certificate" stating to be the greatest player, see:

> rubber-stamped; rubber-stamping; rubber-stamps
>
> to approve, endorse, or dispose of as a matter of routine or at the command of another

from [Merriam Webster: rubber stamp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rubber%20stamp)

**it** refers to his last achievement, the World Cup win, there are no more stamps needed...

Comment: a. Why did you cite the meaning of the verb when it was used as a noun in the article? b. Is it understandable to refer to the World Cup win as a "rubber stamp", which I think carries a negative connotation?

Comment: "Rubber stamp" doesn't carry a negative connotation in this context. You are supposed to reveal your research and any background information or thoughts in the question, so you should explain in the question what you think. "Rubber stamp" often indicates something which doesn't have great significance in itself but has significance following other things, but that is not a negative connotation.

Comment: @StuartF What do you mean by "has significance following other things"? Even if it can mean something positive, I don't think the World Cup win should be described as a "rubber stamp", do you?